# How does the console obtain the stack trace of an exception?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, stack-trace

In C# I'm trying to modify the `StackTrace` property of a custom exception I created. For this, I just override the `StackTrace` getter and it seems to be working (`Exception` has it as a `virtual` method, so it should work). This is my custom exception:

```
class CustomTimeoutException : Exception
{
    private string oldStack;

    public CustomTimeoutException(string message, String stack)
        : base(message)
    {
        oldStack = stack;
    }

    public override string StackTrace
    {
        get
        {

            return oldStack;
        }
    }
    public override string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return "lalalala2";
        }
    }

    public override System.Collections.IDictionary Data
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

I'm using this class the following way:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.throwTimeout2();
        }
        catch(TimeoutException e)
        {
            CustomTimeoutException tor = new CustomTimeoutException(e.Message + "with more", e.StackTrace);
            Console.WriteLine(tor);
            Console.WriteLine(tor.StackTrace);
            throw tor;
        }
    }
    public void throwTimeout2()
    {
        throwTimeout();
    }
    public void throwTimeout()
    {
        throw new TimeoutException("this is a message ");
    }
}
```

When I write the property `StackTrace` to the console, it prints the `StackTrace` of the `TimeoutException`, which means it's in fact overriding it. But, when the console shows the error, the `StackTrace` is not the one it gets from my property, yet the `Message` is the one it gets from the `Message` property I'm also overriding.

So, where does the console get the `StackTrace` of the exception from? I'm using Visual Studio for running.

Comment: Why are you trying to override the `StackTrace` of an Exception? In almost every case, modifying the stack trace is a bad idea.

Comment: @JustinNiessner I'm trying to change the exception message without loosing the stack trace of the exception. I want to do so because I have a tool that uses the message, and I need to extend it. Finally, doing `new Exception("new message", innerOldException)` is not an option, because the tool I'm using uses the most inner exception (I don't have access to change the tool), so it would keep using the message of the old inner exception, instead of my message.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It seems you did not find my answer useful, never mind the actual answer to your problem. Please edit your question, to improve it and make clear what your actual question is (and in particular, contrast that with the information I've provided, explaining why that information is not useful to you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Note: one thing I still really don't understand about your question is that, while you seem to be asking for a way to affect how an exception is reported to the console, you also say that you have some "tool" that apparently has access to the `Exception` object itself and is reporting on the inner-most exception, i.e. following the `InnerException` property chain until it reaches the last one. These two statements seem to be in contradiction with each other, so I'm not really sure I completely understand the question. Still, I spent some time looking into it, and will share what I have regardless. :) .)*

IMHO, there is not a good way to do what you want. There is an ugly way (see below), but I don't recommend it. Especially since your main limitation is the ["tool that uses the message"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35493847/net-how-does-the-console-obtains-the-stack-trace-of-an-exception#comment58680584_35493847); it is IMHO a *very* bad idea to go changing production code just to suit some tool. That path leads to big maintenance headaches, if not outright buggy code.

If you *really* must change the exception message, you should just bite the bullet and toss the entire stack trace text you want to preserve into the message as well. Trying to mess around with the stack trace of the eventually-thrown exception itself is bad news.

That said…

If you were to add diagnostic calls to `Console.WriteLine()` to your method overrides, you would confirm (as you've probably already guessed) that the `StackTrace` property is not called when the exception is re-thrown and reported by the CLR to the console. Overriding the property is not going to help.

There are at least two problems with trying that strategy:

1. The `StackTrace` property is just a `string` containing formatted information about the stack trace. The `Exception` object does actually contain a private field `_stackTrace`. When you execute the `throw` statement with an `Exception` object, the CLR stores the current stack trace information into this field. You would have to find some way to overwrite this field after the fact, to fake a throw site different from the actual one.
2. The CLR exception handling leverages existing Windows exception handling infrastructure. One of the first things that happens when an exception is thrown is the exception handling code attempts to find a handler up the stack. If it fails to find one, then you get the "Unhandled Exception:" message. But note that in the process, the stack has not been unwound. Thus, the exception handling code does not even need to inspect the `Exception` object at all to determine the throw site; the stack is still there, and its state can be reported directly. There is literally *nothing* you can do with the `Exception` object that would affect reporting, if indeed the exception handling code is looking directly at the stack state.

Now, as it happens, for the version of .NET I'm running on my Windows 8.1 machine, it appears that the CLR is reporting the stack trace as stored in the `Exception` object and *not* directly inspecting the stack, per option #2 above. So something like this actually works:

**ExceptionWrapper class**

```
class ExceptionWrapper : Exception
{
    private readonly string _trace;
    private readonly string _message;
    private readonly string _toString;
    private readonly object _stackTrace;

    public ExceptionWrapper(Exception e)
    {
        _trace = e.StackTrace;
        _message = e.Message + ", wrapped";
        _toString = e.ToString();
        _stackTrace = typeof(Exception).GetField("_stackTrace",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(e);
    }

    public override string StackTrace { get { return _trace; } }

    public override string Message
    {
        get
        {
            typeof(Exception)
                .GetField("_stackTrace", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .SetValue(this, _stackTrace);
            return _message;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString() { return _toString; }
}
```

**Test program**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            M1();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static void M1()
    {
        try
        {
            M();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new ExceptionWrapper(e);
        }
    }

    static void M()
    {
        throw new Exception("test exception");
    }
}
```

There is a **very** significant caveat though. This works only because of two specific facts:

1. The CLR is not taking advantage of the current stack state, but instead is trusting the `Exception` object to contain correct stack information in the `_stackTrace` field.
2. The CLR calls the `Message` getter of the `Exception` object before retrieving the stack trace. This gives the object an opportunity to overwrite the `_stackTrace` field before the CLR accesses it for the purpose of reporting the stack trace.

Both of these are, as near as I can tell, completely undocumented implementation details. The second one in particular is *very* fragile; while I can see why the CLR might always have to stick with the first detail, I see no reason at all that Microsoft (never mind other implementors of the CLS) should feel compelled to preserve the behavior in the second point.

Writing code that relies on these implementation details is just asking for trouble. Whatever the broader goal here is, I simply cannot imagine it would be worthwhile to suffer the risk of breaking your project for this need. IMHO, it would be much more reasonable to simply rewrite this "tool" you are trying to accommodate.

Tools are (or at least should be) inherently simple in nature, and not only would rewriting it allow you to produce the results you want without mucking around with private implementation details in third-party code, it would also give you the chance to **a)** add new features, such as providing options for controlling how to process exception data (e.g. looking at something other than the inner-most exception), and **b)** have a tool for which you *do* have the source code, with which you can make further improvements in the future.

I strongly advise that you not paint yourself into this particular corner. :)